# How to handle special chars in the field name of a JSON payload

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I need to handle a payload with special chars in field names like

```
{
   "name" : "bob",
   "address(location)": "somewhere"
}
```

using Django rest framework I can have serializer like:

```
class ContactSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    name = serializers.CharField()
    address = serializers.CharField()
```

but Djrf fails to map "address(location)" to "address", how can I do this ?

I cannot change the payload structure and the serializer complains "address" is missing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Override the **`__init__()`** method,

```
class ContactSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    name = serializers.CharField()

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['address(location)'] = serializers.CharField()
```

Comment: anyway to map it to an  "address" attribute on the serializer? like and alias ?